# How do deselect columns from pydatable frame?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a datatable frame with about 30 columns, here I wanted to look at only 26 cols by keeping the remaining 4 columns a side in Frame,

would the unary operator be useful to deselect the columns as follows

```
DT[:,-(f.x)]
```

I have tried it but it's inserting the operator to the column values, could you please let me know how to do it in pydatatable way?.

Comment: Why don't you try `DT.loc[:,:26]`

Comment: They are not in order, if I don’t want middle 5,8,12 cols??

Comment: Then you have to select them manually like `selected_cols =['col1',col2',...]` and `DT[DT.columns[selected_cols ]`

Comment: You can try this as well  `excluding _cols = =['col1',col2',...]` `df= df.drop(excluding _cols, axis=1)`

Comment: It won’t work in pydatatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `.remove()` can be used to remove columns from an existing column selection. If you need to select all columns except for a few, then first select all columns using `f[:]`, then remove those you don't like. Thus:

```
>>> from datatable import f, dt
>>> DT = dt.Frame(names=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

>>> DT[:, f[:].remove(f.E)]
   |  A   B   C   D   F   G   H   I   J
-- + --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --

[0 rows x 9 columns]

>>> DT[:, f[:].remove([f.B, f.G, f.J])]
   |  A   C   D   E   F   H   I
-- + --  --  --  --  --  --  --

[0 rows x 7 columns]
```

See https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/f-expressions.html#modifying-a-columnset for more details

Comment: Pasha, i have another question: here i have framed a custom function to deselect the passed fields as showed in this code, def pydt_select_mult_cols(DT,*cols):
                                                                  list_of_cols = [*cols]
                                                                  return DT[:,f[:].remove([list_of_cols])].. this is not working,  would you like to give any input ?.

Comment: here is a function to select the required fields from DT.. def pydt_select_mult_cols(DT,*cols):
    list_of_cols = [*cols]
    return DT[:,list_of_cols], It's working in this case.

Comment: Could you please write yours comments for this case?